# osmdroid: Tile server which allows bulk download

Tags: osmdroid

I am working on an application, for which I need to be able to use map data, while offline. I have looked up how to use the CacheManager and how to download tiles referencing the [SampleCacheDownloader.java](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/OpenStreetMapViewer/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/samplefragments/cache/SampleCacheDownloader.java).

I am using the following code to download the tiles:

```
CacheManager cMgr = new CacheManager(map);
BoundingBox bBox = cMgr.extendedBoundsFromGeoPoints(currentGeoPoints, 16);

cMgr.downloadAreaAsync(this, bBox, 16, 21, new CacheManager.CacheManagerCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onTaskComplete() {
    }

    @Override
    public void updateProgress(int progress, int currentZoomLevel, int zoomMin, int zoomMax) {
    }

    @Override
    public void downloadStarted() {
    }

    @Override
    public void setPossibleTilesInArea(int total) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskFailed(int errors) {
    }
});
```

The code works, as in starting the download. But all the tile servers, which are included in the TileSourceFactory class either throw the TileSourcePolicyException "This online tile source doesn't support bulk download" (e.g. MAPNIK and WIKIMEDIA) or fail to get the tiles, because they don't exist for the set zoom levels (e.g. USGS_SAT and USGS_TOPO).

So my question is, are there other publicly available tile servers or do I have to set up my own to be able to download tiles in bulk? Or do I have the completely wrong approach to caching the tiles included in a bounding box with set zoom levels?

Comment: Sure, there are many tile providers. Some may have limited free plans too. There's e.g. geofabrik.de, geoapify.com, jawg.io, maptilesapi.com, stadiamaps.com, thunderforest.com, maptiler.com but I haven't checked their bulk download policies.

Comment: The sample `Cache Manager` demo is available at play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.osmdroid under the `Events` section. Please test it to see if it works as expected.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen They either don't allow bulk download, or only in one of the high cost plans.

Comment: @ecle What tile server does the demo use? The Cache Manager works completely fine in my code, it is just, that the tile servers, which are built-in, don't allow bulk downloads or have tiles missing (i.e. USGS_SAT and USGS_TOPO).

Comment: @Geshode Based on its source code, it says TileSourceFactory.USGS_SAT

Comment: @geshode https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/1297

Comment: Need to use a different user-agent string instead of "osmdroid" to bypass the OSM tile server restriction?

Comment: That is why I resort to using file-based offline maps like Geopackage which OsmDroid supports. The bonus is that you can also use the GeoPackage library API feature to load from a tile server URL, instead of a GPKG file.

Comment: Official Geopackage sample app Mapcache from National Geospatial-Intelligence Agency (NGA) shows its features https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mil.nga.mapcache&hl=en&gl=US. I have adapted the sample app code to use OsmDroid MapView API instead of GMaps API for my app.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after I updated osmdroid-android lib from 5.6.5 to 6.1.18.

It look like the guys from osm decided to reduce the load to main server and force the map sources policies. So, now the bulk tiles download is forbidden for some tile sources. But, the old version still work. I think it means that basically the old urls are valid and allow bulk download and it is not against the policy.

I guess you can just configure a tile source similar how it was in old library:

```
    public static ITileSource MAP_DATA_SOURCE = new XYTileSource("Mapnik",
        0, 19, 256, ".png", new String[] {
        "http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/",
        "http://b.tile.openstreetmap.org/",
        "http://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/" },
        "© OpenStreetMap contributors");
```